# Returning GUI back after Nimbus setting

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, nimbus

New to java and have a problem I cannot seem to fix no matter what I do, so any
help will be greatly appreciated.

I have a little application in Java and have integrated a pop up calendar (WWW)
avaiable which uses the Nimbus look and feel. My problem is that I am unable to 
get the same look and feel for my GUI after the pop up calendar gets invoked for
the first time.  I have two choices. either to find a way to reset the settings so
that my GUI is as before and call to the pop up are made or to enter some code not
sure where(Main class) so that all the GUI uses the nimbus look and feel.

Here is the code for the pop up calendar

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.UIManager.*;

public  class Celendar extends JFrame {
    //private JPanel p;
    Celendar(){
    //super("ColorEditor");
         //UIManager.put("nimbusBase", new Color(233,22,22));
         //UIManager.put("nimbusBlueGrey", new Color(22,200,150));
         //UIManager.put("control", new Color(100,150,200));


    try {
        for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }else{
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel"com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    // If Nimbus is not available, you can set the GUI to another look and
    // feel 
    }

    setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
    setSize(322,250);
    setLocation(500,400);
    setResizable(false);
    Days d= new Days();

    /*----- Here -----*/
    //setVisible(true);
    //setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    I THINK HERE IS WHERE I NEED TO INSERT SOME CODE TO GET MY GUI DISPLAYING
    BEFORE THECALL TO THE POP UP IS MADE.


    /*----------------*/
    add(d);

    // try{
    //   //UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    //   //UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
    //     UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
    //   //UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel");
    //   //UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel");
    //   //UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
    //   SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);
    //  }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("error "+e);}
    }
}
```

Or where do I insert code to make all my GUI have the nimbus look and feel

Comment: New to Java, huh? I wish you very, very much luck. At least try to have fun. :) Oh, and please indent your code with four spaces, see the formatting rules. Welcome! :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want all UIs to have the same L&F, put that code that sets it before any UI or component is created; typically right in `main(String[])` or in the constructor of your first UI that is created.  You could also set the L&F back after you are done with the calendar by calling `UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()`.  Think is that once you set the L&F, all components created after that will get that L&F (if you didn't already know that).

Comment: Hi Merky,Thank you for your help here is my Main where do I insert it please?public static void main(String args[]) { SA md=new SA("Stock Program ™ Copyright© 2010 Simon Andi"); Dimension sd=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize(); md.setLocation(sd.width/2-400/2, sd.height/2-400/2); md.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); } thanks Simon

Comment: Sory Merky false alarm not working at all how do I change it back to java GUI look and feel please with UImanager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName?

Comment: Sorted it - Thanks for all the replys.  Simon

Comment: Sorry, was not working (on EST in the US) so I didn't see your questions.  So did you get what you needed?